# Merge two pandas dataframe with small margin of errors on each row's selected value?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Two dataframes' `key1` are increasing at linear rate, but there might be some error.

df1

```
key1 key2 key 3
  0   1    2
 20   3    4
 40   5    6    <- this row
 60   7    8
```

df2

```
key1 key4 key5
  0   9    10
 20   11   12
 39   13   14    <- this row
 60   15   16
```

After merging df1 and df2, the result should be:

df3

```
key1 key2 key3 key4 key5
  0   1    2    9    10
 20   3    4    11   12
 40   5    6    13   14    <- this row
 60   7    8    15   16
```

The value used for merged df on the row should be a int that is rounded arithmetic mean.

I tried to create a nested for loop going through df1 and df2 and check the values on `key1`, if the difference on value is larger than 1, I'll just append a new row to df3 with `nan` in the missing part.

eg:

some row in df1:

```
key1 key2 key 3
100   20   21
```

some row in df2:

```
key1 key4 key5
105   22   23
```

What should be added to df3:

```
key1 key2 key3 key4 key5
100   20   21   nan  nan
105   nan  nan  22   23
```

This approach is very slow and my computer only finished 4% of the processing overnight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`pd.merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html) was intended for this:

```
df3 = pd.merge_asof(df1, df2, on='key1')
```

Output:

```
>>> df3
   key1  key2  key3  key4  key5
0     0     1     2     9    10
1    20     3     4    11    12
2    40     5     6    13    14
3    60     7     8    15    16
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! It worked well but there are still some issue:

Is it possible that `merge_asof()` can preserve unmatched rows?

I checked its documentation but it didn't specify any.

Comment: @StepBroBD it doens't look like it. But, I think there's a way. It appears that `merge_asof` uses the `key1` from the first df, so we can just select the rows from the *second* df where `key1` isn't in the the merged df. `df2[~df3['key1'].isin(df2['key1'])]`